# How to declare a global const initialized by a function in the header?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an older source code, like this, in a header used from many places in my project:

```
const int myVar = myFunc();
```

What I want:

- Being a global, const variable, I would like if it would be linked only once in the binary.
- Thus, also `myFunc()` should be called only once in the global variable initialization phase.

Now the problem is that I get this warning from the `.cc` I compile:

```
In file included from mySource.cc:7:0:
myHeader.h:59:11: warning: ‘myVar’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 const int myVar = myFunc();
       ^
```

Note, `mySource.cc` really doesn't use `myVar`, thus the warning is okay, but other sources yes.

I think, the best would be if I would declare `myVar` only in the header, some like so:

myHeader.h:

```
 int myVar;
```

mySource.cc:

```
 int myVar = myFunc();
```

But in this case, I can't declare it as const. *This variable should be a const.* Yes, I know it will be on a writable memory page, only the c++ will see it as a constant, but this is exactly what I want.

Thus, I also want to avoid this warning. Furthermore, I think `myFunc()` would be called many times, what I don't want.

How can I do this?

Comment: `const` variables have internal linkage.  Not sure if you can change that.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, just add `extern`. But then you run into multiple definition problems, because they then name the same object.

Comment: @Nathan, not neccesarily. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to split definition and declaration, and define the variable in the cpp file, like following:

In .h:

```
extern const int myVar;
```

In .cpp:

```
const int myVar = myFunc();
```

In C++17, inline variable would be the way to go:

```
inline const int myVar = myFunc();
```